# How to burn a set of AVI files with corresponding subs to DVD

Tags: dvd, burning, avi, subtitles

I have a movie splitted in 3 .avi files with corresponding subtitles (.srt) to each of them. Is there any program (preferably for Linux) which can burn the complete movie to a DVD?